# Class Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Increment\Numeric does not exist in magento 2.0.7

Tags: magento2, migration, magento2-migration-tool

After Migration from Magento 1.9.2.4 to Magento 2.0.7 when I go to create a customer and fill all the information and click on submit, it show me error

```
We can\'t save the customer.
```

After debug I found the error below:-

```
Class Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Increment\Numeric does not exist
```

How can I solve it.

Where I get the missing file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long and hectic time spend on this issue finally I found the solution for this:

First Go to phpmyadmin for magento2 database and run the below query:

```
SELECT * FROM `eav_entity_type` WHERE `increment_model` = 'Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Increment\\Numeric'
```

Now run the below queries to update the `increment_model`:

```
UPDATE `avanteksrv_mage207`.`eav_entity_type` SET `increment_model` = 'Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Increment\\NumericValue' WHERE `eav_entity_type`.`entity_type_id` =1;
UPDATE `avanteksrv_mage207`.`eav_entity_type` SET `increment_model` = 'Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Increment\\NumericValue' WHERE `eav_entity_type`.`entity_type_id` =5;
UPDATE `avanteksrv_mage207`.`eav_entity_type` SET `increment_model` = 'Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Increment\\NumericValue' WHERE `eav_entity_type`.`entity_type_id` =6;
UPDATE `avanteksrv_mage207`.`eav_entity_type` SET `increment_model` = 'Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Increment\\NumericValue' WHERE `eav_entity_type`.`entity_type_id` =7;
UPDATE `avanteksrv_mage207`.`eav_entity_type` SET `increment_model` = 'Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Increment\\NumericValue' WHERE `eav_entity_type`.`entity_type_id` =8;
```

conclusion:
we need to update the `increment_model` from `Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Increment\Numeric` to `Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Increment\NumericValue`

Happy coding!!

Comment: Can use a single SQL update query ```UPDATE `eav_entity_type` SET `increment_model`= 'Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Increment\\NumericValue' WHERE `increment_model` = 'Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Increment\\Numeric';```

Comment: yes you can update single value using single query